# Is there a way to look for the plus sign (+) in google sheets with REGEXMATCH

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, arguments, google-sheets-formula, special-characters

Hello i am trying to "scan" a cell with google sheets REGEXMATCH function where i want to look for the plus sign (+) in the cell and if it is there i want to run a fucntion like this

`=IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B2);"+");1+(B2/100);B2)`

A little side info i am not sure if you guys have to use simicolons (;) like i do, but thats the only thing that works for me, but on youtube they use commas (,)

I have tried putting parenthesis () around the plus thinking that might have made it possible to look for a plus sign (+), but that dident really help just said the same error that the plus sign is not a regular option to look for
`=IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B2);"+");1+(B2/100);B2)`

Comment: Comma (,) and semicolon (;) depends on locale and regional settings. Show some input and expected output.

Comment: Put a ```\``` before the `+` (`"\+"`) to escape it.